# What is a one word noun for Ethereum?

Tags: network

Suppose I have the following sentence in writing:

*"MyCoolDApp is an application built on the Ethereum _______."*

What is the best word in the blank? Platform, Network, System, or Blockchain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in the ethereum official [website](https://www.ethereum.org/) they define it as :

> Ethereum is a  decentralized **platform** that runs smart contracts

so when we talk about Dapps it is more logic to talk about platform rather than blockchain, network or even system. so my answer is

"MyCoolDApp is an application built on the Ethereum **platform**."